# Solving fractional knapsack problem with dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

A few days ago, I was reading about greedy algorithms and dynamic programming for the fractional knapsack problem, and I saw that this problem can be solved optimally with the greedy method. Can anyone give an example or a solution to solve this problem with the dynamic programming method?

P.S: I know that the greedy method is the best way to solve this question, but I want to know how dynamic programming works for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can solve the problem with dynamic programming.

Let `f(i, j)` denote the maximum total value that can be obtained using the first `i` elements using a knapsack whose capacity is `j`.

If you are familiar with the 0-1 knapsack problem, then you may remember that we had the exact same function. However, the recurrence for the 0-1 knapsack problem was `f(i, j) = max{f(i - 1, j), V[i] + f(i - 1, j - W[i])}` (the first argument considers the case in which we don't take the item at index `i`, and the second argument considers the case in which we do take the item at index `i`).

In the fractional knapsack problem, we are allowed to take *fractional* amounts of some item. Thus, our recurrence would look something like, `f(i, j) = max{f(i - 1, j), delta * V[i] f(i - 1, j - delta * W[i])` over all possible values of `delta`, where `delta` represents the amount of the item that we are taking.

Now if you increment `delta` in sufficiently small increments, you should get the correct answer.

Comment: `if you increment delta in sufficiently small increments, you should get the correct answer` so it reverts to multi-parameter optimization problem, does not look appropriate for dynamic programing approach  ;-)

Comment: It would be great if you cite your answer.